# navigation bar move from left to right or right to left when click back button on landscape mode

Tags: objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, core-animation, uinavigationbar

on landscape mode, when i click back button on navigation bar, the navigation bar will move down then show the previous view controller's view. Is it possible to make navigation bar move in left-right direction when clicking back button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yon can create custom animations for back button.

You can refer to this Stack Overflow question : [Back button animation in  Navigation controller](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3146452/878414)