# How to push ViewController with slide effect from left to right? Animation name required

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, slide

**EDIT:**

- What is the animation name of the gif below (from right to left)?
- What is the animation name of the complementary animation of the gif below (from left to right)?

**NOTE:** I don't want to push a segue. I want to push a view with that animation.

---

**EDIT 2:**

Some people are confused when I talk about animation names. However here is an example of an animation name that works (name is: **UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromRight**):

```
    [UIView  beginAnimations: @"Showinfo"context: nil];
    [UIView setAnimationCurve: UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.75];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController: view animated:NO];
    [UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromRight forView:self.navigationController.view cache:NO];
    [UIView commitAnimations];
```

I am using push and pop to recall the actions on a stack. I believe that Navigation controller keeps the navigation in a stack style structure.

---

I am using a Navigation controller and I like the effect that I get when I go back (pop) to the previous view using the navigation bar item. It is a nice and smooth from right to left effect.

This is an example of a **from right to left effect**:

[image]

How can I create the complementary a **from right to left effect**? 
In other words when I go down in the view hierarchy?

This is how I push the view controller at the moment:

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:view animated:YES];
```

Comment: Why are you suggesting this?

Comment: If I understand well : you want a 'pop' animation on a 'push' ?

Comment: What are the names of these animations?

Comment: @Vinzz I just want to understand what the animation name is of the effect in the gif above so I can then search for it and its complementary and use it at my will in my code.

Comment: @MuhammadAdnan I don't want to push a segue. I want to push a view with that animation.

Comment: "Push a segue" means nothing. Of course you are pushing a view, segue is just a link. When people speak about "a push segue", it's about a segue between two views with a push animation.

Comment: 'push a view' ? I don't know what that means... There are 3 types of ViewController transitions you can customize : UIViewController `presentViewController:animated:` UINavigationController push & pop transitions, and UITabBarController tab change.  Which case is yours ?

Answer (score 1):

We need to add CATransition animation for our viewController. look at this,

```
    add <CAAnimationDelegate> in your .h file

    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle: nil];
    ViewController *VC = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@ViewController"];
    CATransition *transition = [CATransition animation];
    transition.duration = 0.45;
    transition.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionDefault];
    transition.type = kCATransitionPush;
    transition.subtype = kCATransitionFromLeft;
    transition.delegate = self;
    [self.navigationController.view.layer addAnimation:transition forKey:nil];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:VC animated:NO];
```

Answer (score 0):

Animation name... Well, there is no unique way of calling an animation, but let's try

- Right to Left slide in (view controller sliding is presented)
- Left to Right slide out (view controller sliding is dismissed)

There are many examples of UIViewController custom transitions out here, see for example : [the github project that re-created sample code for WWDC Session 218: Custom Transitions Using View Controllers](https://github.com/soleares/SOLPresentingFun) (the class of interest to you should be `SOLSlideTransitionAnimator`, which enables all kinds of 'slide' animations )

**EDIT**

Ok, you're not talking about animations names, but you're mixing 2 APIs, that are somehow related :

- UIView animtions (by the way, you're using the OLD API, newer API with Blocks is preferred )

From [Apple UIView documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/UIView/beginAnimations:context:)

> Use of this method is discouraged in iOS 4.0 and later. You should use the block-based animation methods to specify your animations instead.

- UIViewController transitions (like navigation push...)

Now, you're embedding a `UINavigationController` push call INSIDE a `UIView` animation transaction. This is **WRONG** !

Why ? Well, calling `UINavigationController` `pushViewController:animated` results in a UIView animation being called - either Apple defaults animations, or you own animation if you provide a `UIViewControllerTransitioningDelegate` to your controller  So basically you're calling an animation inside an animation...

Apple has provided way to customize animations since iOS 7, and you should use that API they provide. This is the API the github sample code I linked to uses. If you need further introduction, read Apple documentation, [or other resources](http://www.objc.io/issue-5/view-controller-transitions.html)

Comment: please see my EDIT 2 for explanation on "animation name"

Answer (score 0):

For Push you are using already correct way by pushing view, but their is no need of any animation code from your side, only below code is sufficient.

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController: view animated:NO];
```

For pop you can add below code in DetailView, which is available from iOS 7.

```
self.navigationController.interactivePopGestureRecognizer.delegate = (id)self;
```